# Comparison of PyEphem with Swiss Ephemeris library

Tags: python, pyephem

I'm about to start a project where I need calculation of planetary ephemeris. For a long time I was considering that [Swiss Ephemeris](http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephinfo_e.htm) library is practically the only serious solution before I've found out about PyEphem.

Now I just wonder if someone did some thorough comparison between the two packages in terms of speed and precision?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are comparaing apples and oranges: the SwissEphemeris provides astrological planetary positions; PyEphem, astronomical.